# Передача результата функции в качестве параметра объекту

Tags: php, интерфейс

Прошу помочь с учебным заданием по главе "Интерфейсы":

Организуйте клонирование объектов класса User таким образом, чтобы пароль пользователя password в клонированном объекте отличался от оригинала.

Стоит сказать, что в главе была описана иерархия наследования пользователей сайта User -> FrontUser (например).

Не понимаю сути задания, а спросить не у кого:
Как я понял, нужно создать класс User с базовыми переменными (и методами), которые будут полезны наследникам (FrontUser).

```
interface Pass {
    public function setPass();
}

class User implements Pass
{
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $email;
    public $password;

    public function __construct (

        $email,
        $password,
        $first_name = null,
        $last_name = null)
    {

        $this->first_name = $first_name;
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function setPass() {
        $this->password = function() {
            $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
            $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
            $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
                $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
                $pass[$i] = $alphabet[$n];
        }
            return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
        };

    }

    public function __clone() {
        $this->password = function() {
            $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
            $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
            $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
                $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
                $pass[$i] = $alphabet[$n];

        }
            return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
        };
    }
}
```

Создаем объект этого класса

```
$userx = new User(
'example@mail.ru',
'pa$$w0rd',
'Andrey',
'Ivanov');
```

После чего клонируем объект userx

```
$usercloned = clone $userx;
```

Прошу подсказать - куда двигаться дальше?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.cloning.php

Comment: @u_mulder да там в классе уже все хорошо прописано